# Calculating drop packets count per link and total count in the whole network

Tags: omnet++

I am new to Inet/Omnet++ and would like to calculate the packet loss ratio for each link in the wireless network. It is obvious that receiving packets which destination address does not match the node is not considered. I assume I have to use this formula :

Packet Loss Ratio = TotalLostPackets / SentPackets

How to calculate the packet loss rate for each link (both sides of a link are in the transmission range of each other) and the sum of drop packets in the whole network in omnet++?
My ned file is:

```
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.contract.IIntegratedVisualizer;

network Net80211
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=650,450;bgi=background/terrain");
    submodules:
        visualizer: <default("IntegratedCanvasVisualizer")> like IIntegratedVisualizer if hasVisualizer() {
            parameters:
                @display("p=640,15;is=s");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                @display("p=640,112;is=s");
        }
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=638,56;is=s");
        }
        host[numHosts]: AdhocHost {
            parameters:
                @display("r=,,#707070;p=300,200;is=s");
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you define "TotalLostPackets" for a wireless network? Let's assume that network contains four nodes. When node number 1 sends a packet it may be received by for example nodes 2 and 3 (that are close to sender) but a node 4 (far away) does not receive that packet. For this example SentPackets=1, but what value should have TotalLostPackets?

Comment: In your example with four nodes, eg n1, n2, n3, and n4. Suppose n1 wants to send 50 packets to n4. Suppose n2 and n3 are in the transmission range of n1 and n4 not in the transmission range of n1. If 47 packets of these 50 packets are received by n4, 3 packets are dropped. So total count drop packets are 3 so far. If n2 wants 26 packets to n3 but 24 packets are received of these 26 packets, the dropped packets count are 2, Total dropped packets in this network are 3+2=5, so TotalLostPackts=5.

Comment: Are you aware that this way Packet Loss Ratio may be greater than 1.0? For example when node n1 sends 50 packets, and n2 receives only 10 (i.e. 40 lost), n3 receives 10 (i.e. 40 lost), TotalLostPackets=80, SentPackets=50, so Packet Loss Ratio=1.6.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are right, the formula is corrected as "PacketLossRatio(source, destination) = 1 - ReceivedPacketCount in destination / SentPacketCount by source" and is defined for a pair of "source and destination", in my example in my own previous comment, the source is n1 and destination is n4. So PacketLossRatio(n1, n4)=1-47/50=0.06. In your example, PacketLossRatio(n1, n2)=1-10/50=0.8 . Also, I have another question, how to log the reason of dropping packet in omnet++?

Comment: INET contains many ready to use examples. Take a look at e.g. examples/adhoc/ieee80211, start the simulation, then in results analyser you may find the following scalars: packetDropQueueOverflow, packetRemoved, packetDropDuplicateDetected, packetDropRetryLimitReached, packetDropNotAddressedToUs.